# JOIN an UPDATE in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

If I have to update statements like so...

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE items SET shrapnel = shrapnel-1000 WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET username = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['username'], $user['id']));
```

Is it possible to join the two? I have tried alot of different methods which just do not work?

Comment: Before we get to the *how*, tell us *why*

Comment: Because I want to learn how to use join syntax on updates, and I also heard joining the queries will improve the speed as 1 query is faster than 2

Comment: If there is any, then it will be insignificant. The only performance increase you're going to get from executing multiple queries is if they affect the same table - the database would only have to recreate the index once. If you're updating two tables you may just as well execute two queries. In fact, it's probably faster to execute two queries since the engine doesn't have to join the rows together first.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE items, accounts SET items.shrapnel = items.shrapnel - 1000, accounts.username = ? WHERE items.id=accounts.id AND accounts.id = ?
```

But frankly, this feels very dangerous.

If you want to ensure that both queries are executed properly, use a transaction instead.

```
$dbc -> beginTransaction();
// queries go here
$dbc -> commit();
```

Comment: Ye I am using transactions and rolling back if I need to, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Look what I found on [mysql UPDATE reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), should be useful!

Multiple-table syntax is this:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions.

But in this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.